# column "p__linq__0" does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am working with Entity Framework 6 and PostgreSQL. I want to do a simple select query but it doesn't work when I use a parameter in the query.

```
// this works fine

string variabletest= "test";
var test2 = _context.clients.Where(s=>s.hostname.Equals("test")).ToList();

// this gives an error

var test2 = _context.clients.Where(s=>s.hostname.Equals(variabletest)).ToList();
```

When using the second test 2 I got the error "column "p__linq__0" does not exist". How to fix this?

Comment: Weird. Have you test `s => s.hostname == "test"` ?

Comment: What changes between the tests? If you debug, what happens to variabletest?

Comment: What provider for PostgreSQL are you using? Is it up to date?

Comment: Yes I also tested s => s.hostname == "test" same error.

Comment: this is the sql generated by EF:                                                
SELECT "Extent1"."hostname", "Extent1"."windows_user_login", "Extent1"."parameter_name", "Extent1"."parameter_value" FROM "public"."clients" AS "Extent1" WHERE "Extent1"."hostname" = @p__linq__0

Comment: this workaround is working `var test2 = _context.clients.Where(s => s.hostname == ("${variabletest}")).ToList();`

Comment: the provider is entityframework6.npgsql